# How to parse a csv file in a dynamically generated download link?

Tags: javascript, java, csv

I want to parse the 50 Viral Songs in Spotify from their CSV file link.

When you see the top right corner in https://spotifycharts.com/viral/?country=us&recurrence=daily&date=latest, there is a download to CSV link.

It's not a static file link. I think the CSV is dynamically generated using Javascript.

Even the url is not that of a static file (https://spotifycharts.com/api/?download=true&limit=50&country=us&recurrence=daily&date=latest&type=viral).

How can I parse this CSV using the URL in Java?

Answer (score 3):

Using Apache [commons-csv](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/):

```
URL url = new URL("https://spotifycharts.com/api/?download=true&limit=50&country=us&recurrence=daily&date=latest&type=viral)");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStreamReader urlStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
CSVParser cvs = new CSVParser(urlStreamReader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
cvs.getRecords().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```